# How to invoke a function within document.ready in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

When I try to invoke a function outside document ready is works but doesn't works inside.

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.addItems(0, 2);
      $(document).ready(() => {
         if($('html').hasClass('fp-enabled')){
                $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');
            }
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({ 
            onLeave: (index, nextIndex, direction) => {
                this.no_of_post = 5;
                if(direction == 'down' && index+1 >= this.no_of_post){
                    const start = this.no_of_post;
                    this.no_of_post += 1;
                    this.addItems(start, index+2);
                    console.log(index+1);
                }
            }
        });
      });
  }

addItems(startIndex, endIndex) {
    for (let i = startIndex; i < endIndex; ++i) {
        this.newService.fetchData().subscribe(data=>{
           this.single_post = data[i];
           this.posts.push(this.single_post);
        }); 
    }
  }
```

The above code works but when I move the `this.addItems(0, 2);` within `$(document).ready(() => {` it doesn't work.

Comment: try replacing arrow function by normal function

Comment: `document.ready` is most probably already emitted before your code is executed, therefore `document.ready` with Angular > 2 doesn't really make sense. Please provide more information about what you actually try to accomplish.

Comment: `this` in your jQuery code has another scope than `this` in your Angular Class. Are you going to post your question every day now?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906533/how-to-communicate-in-angular-4-app-with-the-dom

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44904184/how-to-access-angular-4-method-from-dom

Comment: Definite duplicate of [How to communicate in Angular 4 app with the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906533/how-to-communicate-in-angular-4-app-with-the-dom)

Comment: Initial I tried using this angular based plugin `ngx-fullpage` but I was having issues with it so I switched to jQuery plugin. What is the hook I can use instead of document ready?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
constructor(
    private zone: NgZone
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        // Your code here, stub for the sake of the example
        document.ready = () => {
            console.log('Code ran when document is ready, and stays in the scope of Angular.');
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: Better : [here is the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone)